# Locate data in out-of-source cmake build without need of copy

Tags: cmake, game-development

I'm porting my game engine to linux and don't know how to locate my data without copying it. Before the data was in myproject/bin together with the produced exectuable.

With cmake default structure, the binaries go under myproject/build/source/launcher/release/launcher.exe separated from the data. I can locate it with visual studio, setting the working directory to the same path(myproject/data). But I would like a general solution directly from cmake. Mosts answers I've read copy the data to each build or generate a path variable pointing to the data. There's to much data to have duplicates for debug/release and it just doesn't feel right to copy it.

What is the best option here? What is most common in game development?

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/caseymcc/CreateLaunchers, with Visual Studio/Windows it will create a .user file(vs debug info) and a batch file that you can set the command, command line args, path to dlls, working directory and any other environment variables you need.

On linux it will produce a shell script with the same info.